# Python multiple stderr pipeing with subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I'm trying to pass down the error pip but I think it's getting lost 
some ware. Here's my code:

```
from subprocess import *
p = Popen(['ps', '-f', '-u', 'root'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
p1 = Popen(['grep', 'top'], stdin=p.stdout, stdout=PIPE, stderr=p.stderr)
p2 = Popen(['grep', '-v', 'grep'], stdin=p1.stdout, 
     stdout=PIPE, stderr=p1.stderr)
p3 = Popen(["awk", "{print $8}"], stdin=p2.stdout, stdout=PIPE,
     stderr=p2.stderr)
out_v, err_v = p3.communicate()
```

I don't seem to be able to get it right, what is it that I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: That's all ? here name 'user' and 'v' is not defined.

Comment: It's not all, just what's relevant, I'll edit it.